# How to I marshall the objects in to Array in JSON using Jersey - This is the GET method

Tags: java, json, jersey

I am trying to get the object in the following format in JSON using the Jersey framework, How can I write this

```
{
  "EmployeeID" : 123,
  "Employee" : { 
       "Name" :"John",
       "address: "1234,eldenSt",
       "Phone": 123456
        } 

}
```

Appreciate your help

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding the @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) annotation to your resource method?

Comment: Yes, I added it, but I am getting the Json as one Object only, but  how can I do get an array inside the Json. as { "EmployeeID" : 123, "Name" :"John", "address: "1234,eldenSt", "Phone": 123456 }

Comment: The JSON output is a representation of your object graph/tree. It looks like you are trying to change the structure of your objects when you serialize them with JSON. I don't think there is a simple way to transform. You would be better of maintaining your objects in the structure you want them output.